# How to accept payments with golang?

Tags: go

I'm making a back-end for my app using Golang the app is for android,ios and windows and i'm trying to find a way to accept payments.
Is there a package that I can use with examples?

Comment: Just a recommendation, use a payment processor and leverage _their_ api. You almost certainly don't want the liability of processing payments yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like some of the comments have mentioned, I also suggest choosing a preferred payment system and then using a Go client library which interfaces with that payment system's REST API.

Here are a few payment libraries: https://golanglibs.com/top?q=payment
Most of these include example files or examples in the readme. Many Go packages also use GoDoc for documentation.

The most popular one on the list there is [PayPal-Go-SDK](https://github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK) which is a Go client for the PayPal REST API. 
It includes an example file: https://github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK/blob/master/example_test.go

It has GoDoc documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/logpacker/PayPal-Go-SDK

If you prefer to use a different payment service like Stripe, they have a similar client: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go

They also have usage examples: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go#usage

They also have documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/stripe/stripe-go